# Sorting a pandas dataframe by its index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, datetime

The following is a sample of my dataframe. As you'll notice, the index (which is datetimeindex) is not sorted.

```
               Item Details  Unit    Op.  Qty Price  Op. Amt.
Month
2013-04-01           5 In 1   Pcs  -56.0     172.78  -9675.58
2014-01-01         14" Blad   Pcs  -5.0      157.49   -787.45
2013-09-01  Zorrik 311 Gram   Pcs  -1.0      270.01   -270.01
```

I wanted to sort the index and its respective rows also. I found the following way to sort the datetimeindex:

```py
all_data.index.sort_values()

DatetimeIndex(['2013-04-01', '2013-04-01', '2013-04-01', '2013-04-01',
           '2013-04-01', '2013-04-01', '2013-04-01', '2013-04-01',
           '2013-04-01', '2013-04-01',
           ...
           '2014-02-01', '2014-02-01', '2014-02-01', '2014-02-01',
           '2014-02-01', '2014-02-01', '2014-02-01', '2014-02-01',
           '2014-02-01', '2014-02-01'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name=u'Month', length=71232, freq=None)
```

But it is sorting only the index; how can I sort the entire **dataframe** according to the sorted index?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I think you need [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
all_data = all_data.sort_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

`df.sort_index()` does the job but if the index is already sorted separately (as in the OP) and you want to sort the dataframe by it, then `loc` is what you want.

```py
sorted_idx = df.index.sort_values()

df = df.loc[sorted_idx]
```

[image: res]