# pd.datetime not indexing correctly

Tags: pandas, datetime, indexing

I have dataset with date of every transaction in restaurant. I tried to set date as index, before converting it with *df.to_datetime*:

```
df['dateTransaction'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dateTransaction'])
df.info()
```

And I really get 'dateTransaction' type as datetime64[ns]. But than I tried to set index with 
`df = df.set_index('dateTransaction')` 
but my dataset didn't sorted by date correctly. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffFAT.png)
Please advice how to index dataframe by date in sorted way?

Comment: Use `df.sort_index(inplace=True)` or `df = df.sort_index()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262710/pandas-sorting-a-dataframe-by-using-datetimeindex is a decent duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `set_index` it never rearranges rows, it just "moves" a column to an index. So you have to explicitly sort (either before or after `set_index`):

```
df = df.set_index('dateTransaction').sort_index()
# or
df = df.sort_values("dateTransaction").set_index('dateTransaction')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading it from CSV you can also try

```
data=pd.read_csv('SomeData.csv',index_col=['Date'],parse_dates=['Date'],dayfirst=True)
```

without `dayfirst=True` the days read in as months and vice versa