# Sanitizing Time Series whose plots shows erratic graph lines

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series, seaborn

I want to plot timelines, my dates are formatted as day/month/year.

When building the index, I take care of that:

```
# format Date
test['DATA'] = pd.to_datetime(test['DATA'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
test.set_index('DATA', inplace=True)
```

and with a double check I see months and days are correctly interpreted:

```
#the number of month reflect the month, not the day : correctly imported!
test['Year'] = test.index.year
test['Month'] = test.index.month   
test['Weekday Name'] = test.index.weekday_name
```

However, when I plot, I see datapoints get connected erratically (although their distribution seems to be correct, since I expect a seasonality):

```
# Start and end of the date range to extract
start, end = '2018-01', '2018-04'

# Plot daily, weekly resampled, and 7-day rolling mean time series together

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(test.loc['2018', 'TMIN °C'],
marker='.', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5, label='Daily')
```

I suspect it may have to do with misinterpreted dates, or that dates are not put in the right sequence, but could not find a way to verify where an error may be.

Could you help validating how to import correctly my timeseries ?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas - Sorting a dataframe by using datetimeindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262710/pandas-sorting-a-dataframe-by-using-datetimeindex)

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it was super simple. I assumed datetime was automatically sorted, instead one must sort :

```
test.loc['2018-01':'2018-03'].sort_index().index #sorted
test.loc['2018-01':'2018-03'].index #not sorted
```

This question may be delated or marked as duplicate, I let it for moderators:

[Pandas - Sorting a dataframe by using datetimeindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40262710/pandas-sorting-a-dataframe-by-using-datetimeindex)